# Which arrow inserts to use?

Tags: archery, arrows

I am new to bow hunting and I am getting my stuff set up and I was wondering what inserts to use for the following Easton shafts:

- 9.5 gpi 400 axis third generation N-fused carbon arrow shaft, nocks and fletchings.
- 9.5 gpi 340 axis high strength carbon arrow shaft, nocks and fletchings.
- 8.1 gpi 500 axis third generation N-fused carbon arrow shaft, nock and fletching

Any help would greatly be appreciated!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each Axis shaft has the "Hidden Insert Technology" (short HIT) and therefore you need a HIT-insert. Normally these shafts are already delivered with such! So be aware that you don't buy additional ones.

> - X HIT conventional inserts included

From [Lancasterarchery](http://www.lancasterarchery.com/easton-axis-n-fused-carbon-arrow-shaft.html)

You can get them for example [here](http://www.3riversarchery.com/easton-axis-hit-insert-kit.html).

---

The Deep Six RPS Steel insert is also compatible but I would absolutely recommend the HIT inserts.

> - X HIT conventional thread inserts - compatible
> - Deep Six RPS steel inserts - compatible

From the official [Axis product site](http://www.eastonhunting.com/products/arrows/axis)

*P.S.: Axis absolutely rock! =)*

*"I shoot Axis because they're tough shafts, but more importantly, I shoot them for the increased penetration I get on big game."* - Fred Eichler

Comment: I am pretty sure these have not come with the inserts as I tried to add broadheads and they just slip in and out of the top pf the shaft.  Thanks you for the awesome and quick response!!   Andy

Comment: @AndyD Glad to help =) You may want to tick the question as answered to let others know that this question is "done" ;) http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/311440